# r: how to simultaneously change multiple column names based on the individual suffix of each column name

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I have received a datasheet `p` autogenerated from a registry and containing 1855 columns. The autogeneration adds `_vX` automatically to each column name where `X` correspond the number of follow-ups. Unfortunately, this creates ridiculously long column names.

Eg

`p$MRI_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10` and `p$MRI_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20`

correspond to the 10th and 20th MRI scan on the same patient. I.e., each column that addresses clinical parameters related to the 10th follow-up ends with `v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10`.

I seek a solution, preferably in `dplyr` or a `function`, that changes the entire `_v1_v2_...."` suffix to `fuX` corresponding to the xth follow-up.

Lets say that `p` looks like:

```
  a_v2 b_v2_v3 a_v2_v3_v4 b_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 a_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20
1    0       1          1                                                                        1                                                                        0
2    1       1          0                                                                        1                                                                        0
```

Expected output:

```
> p
  a_fu2 b_fu3 a_fu4 b_fu20 a_fu20
1     0     1     1      1      0
2     1     1     0      1      0
```

Data

```
p <- structure(list(dia_maxrd_v2 = c(0, 1), hear_sev_v2_v3 = c(1, 1), reop_ind_v2_v3_v4___1 = c(1, 
0), neuro_def_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 = c(1, 
1), symp_pre_lokal_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 = c(0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**EDIT**

To complicate things, some column names end with "___1" indicating a specific parameter relating to that clinical parameter and should be preserved, e.g.: `_v1_v2_v3_v4___1`. Hence, this is still to be considered as `fu4` and the `___1` part should not be omitted.

```
  a_v2 b_v2_v3 a_v2_v3_v4___1 b_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 a_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20
1    0       1              1                                                                        1                                                                        0
2    1       1              0                                                                        1                                                                        0
```

Expected output:

```
> p
  a_fu2 b_fu3 a_fu4___1 b_fu20 a_fu20
1     0     1     1          1      0
2     1     1     0          1      0
```

**EDIT**

My apologies, the solution must consider the "basic" column name specifying what parameter the column contain, e.g. post-surgical complications. It is *only* the `_v1_v2_v3..._vX`-part that should be substituted with the corresponding `fuX`. What comes *before* and *after* the `_v1_v2_v3..._vX`-part must be preserved.

Consider

```
  dia_maxrd_v2 hear_sev_v2_v3 reop_ind_v2_v3_v4___1 neuro_def_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20 symp_pre_lokal_v1_v2_v3_v4_v5_v6_v7_v8_v9_v10_v11_v12_v13_v14_v15_v16_v17_v18_v19_v20
1            0              1                     1                                                                                1                                                                                     0
2            1              1                     0                                                                                1                                                                         0
```

Expected output:

```
> p
  dia_maxrd_fu2 hear_sev_fu3 reop_ind_fu4___1 neuro_def_fu20 symp_pre_lokal_fu20
1             0            1                1              1          0
2             1            1                0              1              0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with two capturing groups:

```r
names(p) <- gsub("^(.).*?(\\d+)$", "\\1_fu\\2", names(p))

p
#>   a_fu2 b_fu3 a_fu4 b_fu20 a_fu20
#> 1     0     1     1      1      0
#> 2     1     1     0      1      0
```

---

**EDIT**

With new requirements stipulated by OP for including in pipe in having some different endings not in original question:

```r
p %>% setNames(gsub("^(.).*?(\\d+_*\\d*)$", "\\1_fu\\2", names(.)))
#>   a_fu2 b_fu3 a_fu4___1 b_fu20 a_fu20
#> 1     0     1         1      1      0
#> 2     1     1         0      1      0
```

---

**EDIT**

For arbitrary starting strings, it may be easiest to `gsub` twice:

```r
p %>% setNames(gsub("(\\d{1,2}_v)+", "", names(.))) %>%
      setNames(gsub("_v(\\d+)", "_fu\\1", names(.)))

#>   dia_maxrd_fu2 hear_sev_fu3 reop_ind_fu4___1 neuro_def_fu20
#> 1             0            1                1              1
#> 2             1            1                0              1
#>   symp_pre_lokal_fu20
#> 1                   0
#> 2                   0
```

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. Can this be integrated into a pipe `... %>% names(p) <- gsub("^(.).*?(\\d+)$", "\\1_fu\\2", names(p)) %>% ... `?

Comment: @cmirian sure, you could do `p %>% setNames(gsub("^(.).*?(\\d+)$", "\\1_fu\\2", names(.)))`

Comment: Thank you - I tried the solution, and it is great. However, there might be some modifications to the column name, which has the consequence that not all column names end with `_vX` - see edit. Hope that there is a work around.

Comment: Your effort is really appreciated. My apologies, I have not been specific enough regarding how the column names preserve other original parts. I have updated the answer again, and I hope that you have time to help me a bit further - thank you in advance.